# How can my WP7 C# app always show the system tray or programmatically expand it?

Tags: windows-phone-7, system-tray, batterylevel

I am writing an Windows Phone 7.5 app.
How can I expand the system tray by c# code?
I want that by app shows the system tray with the battery status if the user clicks on a specific button.
If the user taps on the clock then normally WP7 expands the system tray and shows the icon for the battery status in system tray. This I would like to do programmatically on an specific actions.
For example the IE does it too: if you click on "..." then the system tray with the battery status icon will be shown.

Is there a possibility to realize this in C#?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the full System Tray you need to call [SystemTray.IsVisible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.systemtray.isvisible%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) whenever the state is changed from `IsVisible=false` to `IsVisible=true` you should get a similar animation to what you saw in IE. The tray will auto hide, as is common in WP, after a short duration.

Keep in mind, it isn't recommended under Metro guidelines.

```
private void Foo()
{
    SystemTray.IsVisible = true;
}
```

Comment: No that is not the case. Only if the phone is charging the animation appears. I tested it with emulator and my device. If I do not tap on the clock manually there is no animation and no battery icon - just the clock.